# Finding the determinant of a generalised matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

For this $n \times n$ matrix I am trying to find the determinant:

$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & ... & n \\
1 & 2^3 & ... & n^3 \\
. & . & ... & . \\
1 & 2^{2n-1} & ...& n^{2n-1}
\end{array}\right]$

I am having abit of trouble with row reduction hence not getting anywhere. I think I need to transform it somehow as it looks similar to a vandermonde matrix but I am not sure how can someone help me out?

Comment: What's the determinant when $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$?

Comment: @CalvinLin 1,6,720,3628800, then they get really big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain why you are stuck.)

**Hint:** Show that the matrix whose entries $a_{ij} = b_i ^j$ has determinant $ \prod_{i > j } ( b_i - b_j)$.

**Hint:** Hence, conclude that the answer is $n! \prod_{i > j} ( i^2 - j^2 ) $.
This matches up with your calculated values when $ n = 1, 2, 3, 4$.

Note: The way the numerical answer is written up is the hint of what matrix you should be considering.